How to use function parameter literal type as return type
Given two types of string identifiers, with types defined as:
type OrgId = `org_${string}`;
type TxnId = `txn_${string}`;

I want to define a function which takes in a string prefix and generates an ID:
function makeId(args: { prefix: string }): string {
  return args.prefix + "_" + Date.now();
}

However, the function is annotated with a string return type. I want it to return the literal type so I can use it like so:
const orgId: OrgId = makeId({ prefix: "org" });
const txnId: TxnId = makeId({ prefix: "txn" });

What I have tried, but failed:
function makeId(args: { prefix: string }): `${typeof args.prefix}_${string}` {
  return args.prefix + "_" + Date.now(); // the concatenation results in a primitive string type
}

How do I define the makeId function return type such that it returns a the literal type instead of string?

Aside: you might consider using a generic type utility to reduce syntax repetition like this

There are two things you'd need to change to make this work:

Use a constrained generic type to allow args.prefix to be a specific string, rather than just any string, for a specific invocation of the function; and
Create the return value with a template literal, rather than concatenation.

For example, this would compile:
function makeId<S extends string>(args: { prefix: S }): `${S}_${string}` {
  return `${args.prefix}_${Date.now()}`;
}

type OrgId = `org_${string}`;

const orgId: OrgId = makeId({ prefix: "org" });

Playground
You could make it more specific with e.g. S extends "org" | "txn" if you have a known set of valid prefixes.

Thank you @jonrsharpe! This is the exact solution I'm looking for but can't wrap my head around defining it.

In addition to @jonrsharpe's answer, you can infer the return type (rather than explicitly specifying it) by using as const after the template string:
function makeId<S extends string>(args: { prefix: S }) {
  return `${args.prefix}_${Date.now()}` as const;
}

type OrgId = `org_${string}`;

const orgId: OrgId = makeId({ prefix: "org" });


I would always recommend specifying rather than inferring the return type - tell the compiler what you intend, then it can actually tell you when that's not what you did. But this does show that \${S}_${number}`` might be a better return type.

Thanks @lionel-rowe for your answer! But I'm with @jonrsharpe on this – I would rather the compiler complain early (line 2) than later during the assignment (last line). That way, I know my return is wrong, instead of having to investigate bottom-up towards the makeId function definition.

I never said this was a better answer, just an alternative answer that achieves the same thing. Certainly I'd recommend explicitly specifying return types for library code. Less so for application code, especially where the return type is simple and/or the function isn't used outside the file where it's declared.
